# CRTP design where base class instantiates members of types specified by the derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp, type-deduction

As described in [crtp-pass-types-from-derived-class-to-base-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921217/crtp-pass-types-from-derived-class-to-base-class) by [Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg), the compiler is unable to deduce the type `Impl::TType` in the declaration of class `Base`:

```
template <typename Impl>
struct Base
{
  typename Impl::TType t;
};

struct MyImplementation : public Base<MyImplementation>
{
  using TType = int;
  TType t;

  MyImplementation(TType n) : t(n) {};
};

int main()
{
  MyImplementation mi(3);

  return 0;
}
```

However, I want a CRTP design where the user writes an implementation which derives from `Base` with the only requirement that the implementation class specifies the type `TType` so that the Base class can instantiate members of that type. In other words, the class `Base` expects the implementation to define type `TType`. For example, it may have to perform the operation on an integer but various implementations can use different int types (e.g. int, unsigned int, long, short ...). `TType` is thus implementation-specific and should not concern the class Base. The brute approach is to do:

```
template <typename Impl, typename T>
struct Base
{
  T t;
};

struct MyImplementation : public Base<MyImplementation, T>
{
  using TType = T;  //uneccessary but left for consistency
  TType t;

  MyImplementation(TType n) : t(n) {};
};
```

But here the type `TType` **does** concern the `Base` and leaves more room for mistakes. For example, if a user wants to template `TType`, he/she is required to write `class MyImplementation : public Base< MyImplementation<T>, T >`, which is a bad API (especially if `Base` requires defining more than one type; e.g. `public Base< MyImplementation<T, V, Q>, T, V, Q >`), making it easy to make mistakes such as:

```
template <typename T, typename Q>
struct MyImplementation : public Base<MyImplementation<T, Q>, Q>
{
  using TType = T;  //user expects that Base will use T as TType, while Q will be used instead
};
```

Is anybody aware of a modern efficient approach to this?

Comment: Is there any issue with the first solution you provided? Can't it reach your goal?

Comment: If you mean the code snippet that has this line `typename Impl::TType request;`, then no. Compiler is not able to deduce what `Impl::TType` is (see the link I provided). If you mean the code snippet below that one, then it works, but I consider it bad API since it allows for the user to pass two different template types and, sometimes, it can be very subtle to recognize that two types are different from each other.

Comment: sorry, I still dont quite understand the quesiton. What exactly would go wrong when a user supplies the wrong type for `T` ? In the code you posted either `TType` can be converted to `T` then I see no problem, it just works as expected. Or `TType` can not be converted to `T` then there is a compiler error. Thats what the code does. What do you want isntead?

Comment: Well yeah, you can say that for everything. But good API is about making it hard to make mistake. If a user has a large codebase and passes `std::vector<bool>::reference` as a template parameter, while expecting class `Base` to work with `bool`, he/she can spend days debugging that. If `Base` was able to deduce `TType` or `?` in `public Base<MyImplementation<T, Q>, ?>` was automatically deduced, `Base` and `MyImplementation` would be guaranteed to deal with the same type.

Comment: you are mixing up things that can cause trouble even though they do compile and things the cause a compiler error. Getting a compiler error does make it hard to make a mistake, because the users code will not compile.Its not obvious what you mean with `std::vector<bool>`. Its `reference` is not `bool&` but in your example thats not an issue. `std::vector<bool>::reference` can be converted to `bool` and your example will work as expected. I am not saying that no problem can exists. I am just saying that it isnt obvious and you didnt say yet what you want to prevent from happening

Comment: are you looking for a way to ensure that `T` is the same type as `TType` ?

Comment: Yes. But if I could do that, I could just use TType?

Comment: The example with `std::vector<bool>::reference` will not work as expected. If `T` is deduced as  `std::vector<bool>::reference` and you write `T b = my_vector[2]`, where `my_vector` is of type `std::vector<bool>`, b will not end up with the value of third member of `my_vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. It is not the nicest, but I think it is manageable and API does not suffer. Let me know if I missed something.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
concept HasTType = requires
{
    typename T::TType;
    // other requirements for the implementation class
};

template <typename T, int S>
class AssertConcept
{
  protected:
    AssertConcept() {
      static_assert(sizeof(typename T::TType) < S, "TType is too big");
      static_assert(HasTType<T>, "concept HasTType not satisfied");
    }
};

template <class Impl, int S = 16>
class Base : private AssertConcept<Impl, S>
{
  private:
    // reserve stack memory for creation of objects of type TType
    std::byte _ptr_ttype[S];

  public:
    Base() {
      // create objects of type TType in the reserved memory
      ::new (static_cast<void*>(_ptr_ttype)) Impl::TType{};
    }

    auto see_value() {return *reinterpret_cast<Impl::TType*>(_ptr_ttype);}

};

struct MyImplementation : public Base<MyImplementation>
{
  using TType = int;
  TType t;

  MyImplementation(TType n) : t(n) {};
};

int main()
{
  MyImplementation mi(3);

  std::cout << mi.see_value() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This will check if the implementation satisfies the concept `HasTType` before class `Base` is instantiated and without any overhead. This is based on the fact that parent class' ctor is invoked before child class' ctor.

Furthermore, if the class `Base` needs to instantiate and manage objects of type `TType`, it can do it using placement new. This has a small overhead because the size of `TType` is unknown and more memory than necessary needs to be allocated, but this can be acceptable in most cases. The user can also pass the size of `TType` as a template argument if he/she wants to avoid this overhead, but I consider this to be better than passing `TType` since the user mostly won't specify the size. Concept also needs to check that the size is not too small.

The alternative is to pass `TType` as a template parameter of `Base`, which is in my opinion a bit worse API-wise, but at least the user can be assured `T`=`TType`.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure if this answers your question, but I have seen that a way around this redundancy is to check for it in the implementation as soon as the nested `TType` is used in the base CRTP class.

(Since, in your case, the Base class is not doing anything, I put it in the constructor for illustration purposes; there might be better places to put the static assert)

```
#include<type_traits>

template <typename Impl, typename T>
struct Base
{
//  typename Impl::TType t;  // not working
    Base() {
      static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, typename Impl::TType>);
    }
};

struct MyImplementation : public Base<MyImplementation, int>
{
  using TType = int;
  TType t;

  MyImplementation(TType n) : t(n) {};
};

int main()
{
  MyImplementation mi(3);

  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TGnn7ofPY

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I consider it unsatisfying because it is just ugly. I hoped somebody would have a really clever way of doing this. Is anybody perhaps familiar with the new cpp reflection features?

Comment: Yes, it is not nice, I have seen this suggested by experts, so I believe there is nothing better. Look at Peter Sommerlad ‘s presentations on strong typedef.

Comment: I think with concepts you can put this as a requirement. Perhaps even as a class level requirement. didn’t try myself.

Comment: fwiw, also a concept takes you only back to square one: `MyImplementation` is incomplete at the point where you need to instantiate `Base<MyImplementation,int>`. I tried it here and the result is an error very similar to the one of the original code https://godbolt.org/z/sqxeqEKT3. The only way is to defer the check to when `MyInstantiation` is complete afaik

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, yes, I wonder what the earlies it can be deferred to, perhaps requirements of a member function, templates of a member functions?

Comment: @lobelk  video "Simplest Strong Typing instead of Language Proposal ( P0109 ) - Peter Sommerlad - [CppNow 2021]" https://youtu.be/ABkxMSbejZI?t=3477

Comment: Imho constructor is just fine. I dont really understand why OP considers it as ugly and unsatisfying. I mean usually the constructor is the first thing to be instantiated. `static_assert` even allows you to add a nice comprehensible error message, something which SFINAE often doesnt achieve (and I am not familiar with concepts, though I suppose they are much better at that)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, the main problem I have is that it needs type traits and not language features, and second, there are many possible constructors to put this in. Besides, it will make the whole thing non-trivially constructible. It's the same thing with the destructor.

Comment: the most important downside I see is that `Base<Foo,double>` is an "ok"  type, even if `Foo` has no member alias for `double`. Though even that I find acceptable

Comment: @alfC You can assert the concept in the ctor of a class that has the only purpose of asserting the concept and is a parent of `Base`. That way, nothing can possibly happen before the concept is asserted.

Comment: @lobelk, that is true. But, does it happen in practice that CRTP bases have other constructors that are not the default constructors? (honest question). All CRTP classes I used do not have other constructors, but I don't know in the wild. If so, one needs to add the check in all the constructors.

Comment: @alfC Sorry, I am not sure if I understood correctly, but I do not see why would one need to check in all the constructors. The default ctor of the parent of `Base` is invoked before any of the ctor of `Base`. Please, look at the solution I provided.

Comment: @lobelk, I mean that the incorrect template parameter can instantiated if the static_assert is not in all the constructors. In that sense, the destructor could be a better place for the check, trading trivial destruction for trivial default construction. See the example here: https://godbolt.org/z/8dvMcPW3f

Comment: @alfC No, static_assert does not need to be in all the constructors. Please, take a look: https://godbolt.org/z/1Tv9GY4Ks

Comment: @lobelk, ok, yes, you are right. unfortunately this doesn’t  help with making the classes trivial. I guess one can put the condition in the destructor as well.